# Limit Column Options in Advanced Find

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 you can create views using advanced find. Inside advanced find, you should define for a specific entity which columns you want to see in the result.

What I want to do is limit or hide specific columns that people can choose for the advanced find.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

> Hi Rob,
>
> Out of the box you can disable a column from being 'searched' --
>   listed in the filtering area of the advanced find.
>
> However, all fields that a user can read are avail for selection in
>   the advanced find.  The only method to change this would be custom
>   code in a 'plug-in'.  Then with a plug-in just about anything is
>   possible as it is compiled code and you could filter out certain
>   columns from being available.
>
> Alex Fagundes - www.PowerObjects.com

Comment: Do you mean search columns or display columns?

Answer (score 3):

The comments by Alex Fagundes, with all due respect, are wrong. As ckeller suggested, you *can* limit the columns displayed to the user, and you certainly don't need a plug-in to do this (nor could you even if you wanted to, so far as I know).

In the client, all you have to do is navigate to the entity the advanced find view of which you want to change, click the "Customize" tab, click "System Views", click on the advanced find view, click "Add Columns", select/deselect the columns you do/don't want to see, then publish your changes.

You can also select/deselect columns of any appropriate related entity this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean search columns (fields they can search by):
To limit the columns they see in an advanced find search, you have a fun job on your hands.

Go to Settings -> Customisations -> and choose the entity you want and list all the fields.

Double click on each field in turn and you will see a drop down menu called 'Searchable'. Set this to 'No' and the field is hidden from Advanced find searches (after you publish your changes).

Repeat this for all fields required.

If you mean fields they see in their results: 
Follow the answer by @jamnap

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Peter will only change the default view for advanced find. The user will still be able to add all columns and customize his own view.

Fields cannot be removed from "add column" in advanced find OOTB. This is what [Alex Fagundes from PowerObjects has written](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/66309/limit-column-options-in-advanced-find/120844).